# Why use the command apt-get --purge remove over apt-get purge in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get

I have been uninstalling applications as well as removing or purging their configuration files using the command `apt-get --purge remove {package_name}`.

I have come across several posts on the net including Ubuntu's guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto that reads `"This command completely removes a package and the associated configuration files. Configuration files residing in ~ are not usually affected by this command"` when just using the command `apt-get purge {package_name}`.

Is there a difference in running the command `apt-get --purge remove {package_name}` and `apt-get purge {package_name}`? Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The command `apt-get --purge remove` has been around since APT was added to Debian and it used to be the only way to completely purge a package with apt.  The command  `apt-get purge` was finally added in the last few years, the old option was not removed, and there is still lots of documentation showing the older syntax.  They do exactly the same thing.

I often still use the longer command `apt-get --purge remove` simply because I have used it more often, and forget that the shorter version is now available.

One other useful thing to keep in mind is that the `--purge` option can be used with the `apt-get autoremove` (equivalent to the shorter `apt-get autopurge`). So if you use `apt-get autoremove` to remove automatically installed packages you will have lots of old crufty configs from those packages, since you just removed them.

Comment: You can purge data from removed packages using `dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge` (command from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Comment: @etam1024 sure, and there are other ways too.  The above just mentions a method to do it in a single operation with autoremove.

Comment: I don't think you understood. As you wrote autoremove removes packages, but "you will have lots of old crufty configs from those packages, since you just removed them". The command I pasted deletes those files. So the commands `apt-get autoremove` and the one pasted together in this order behave like autopurge.